# Implicit equation for the image of immersion $(\cosh(t),\sinh(t))$

Tags: differential-topology, implicit-function-theorem

how can I discribe a implicit equation for the Image of
$$
f(t)=(\cosh(t),\sinh(t)),
$$
knowing that this is an injective immersion? This doesn't look that hard, but I can't proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that $x^2-y^2=1$ so your image is contained in the hyperbola. Also, since $\cosh t>0$ your image is the right branch of the above equilateral hyperbola.